# Setting up a private composer remote repository in Artifactory

Tags: composer-php, artifactory

our team is currently in the process of setting up a local Artifactory instance which is suppose to connect to a private remote repository containing ELTS releases of TYPO3.
The official manual specifies, that you have to include the private repository and set up HTTP basic authentication:

1. *Modify composer.json:*

   ```
   "repositories": [
       {"type": "composer", "url": "https://elts.typo3.com"}
   ]
   ```
2. *Call* `composer config --auth http-basic.elts.typo3.com [YOUR-USER-NAME] [AUTH-TOKEN]` *to add the credentials to the auth.json file.*

When performing these steps locally, composer can fetch packages from the private repository without any issues and writes the follwing to `composer.lock`:

```
        {
            "name": "typo3/cms",
            "version": "v8.7.34",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "git@github.com:TYPO3GmbH/elts-8.7-release.git",
                "reference": "****************redacted****************"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://elts.typo3.com/dist/typo3/cms/typo3-cms-****************redacted****************-zip-******.zip",
                "reference": "****************redacted****************",
                "shasum": "****************redacted****************"
            },
```

However, when we mirror the same configuration on our Artifactory server (version 7.5.x) clients are unable to fetch packages, as API calls requesting the specific package version result in an HTTP 404 error.

Unfortunately, the Artifactory logs are not of much help either, as they don't explain *why* the client requests are met with an HTTP 404 error.

This is our current configuration:

[image: Screenshot of the 'Basic' category of the remote repository configuration page]
[image: Screenshot of the upper 'Advanced' category of the remote repository configuration page]
[image: Screenshot of the lower 'Advanced' category of the remote repository configuration page]

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could point us in the right direction!
Thanks!

Comment: I bet your composer client respond with Not Found packages.json error?
We are experiencing the same thing!

Comment: @kirugan I am having the same error; Did you ever find a solution you'd be willing to share?